# Infinite $digest Loop in AngularJS with Google Charts

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, google-visualization

I am having following error when I run my Asp.NET project built using (AngularJS, BreezeJS & WebAPI). The error is occurring on page where I am using Google Charts API to display chart on page.
**Note: The same code is working fine on other machine** even other pages where I am not using **Goggle Charts** are working correctly on the same system.

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.18/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=[[…22Dates\"}},\"type\":\"AreaChart\"}"]%
```

I opened the error URL in browser but I couldn't find the main issue. The error URL explains why the error came:

**Infinite $digest Loop**

But I could not identify the reason why the same code is working fine on one system & not working on another system?

Thanks

Comment: remove `.min` from the path to your angular.js to see a more descriptive error

Comment: the line where you are getting error 
try this (Timeout)
$timeout(function(){
//will work after digest
});